# How to change href color on click using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to change the color of selected language to be highlighted on click, Below is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a[href*='lang']").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#header-top a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }); 
});
```

### JSP code:

```
<div id="header-top">
    <a href="/eidsar" title="Logo"> 
        <img class="logo" src="/eidsar/images/MobistarLogo.jpg" />
    </a>
    <ul class="lang-nav">
        <li><a class="active" href="?lang=en" title="en">EN</a></li>
        <li><a href="?lang=fr" title="fr">FR</a></li>
        <li><a href="?lang=nl" title="nl">NL</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

### CSS:

```
.lang-nav {
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: 1100px;
    line-height: 42px;
}

.lang-nav li {
    display: inline;
    margin: 0 5px;
}

.lang-nav li a {
    color: #999999;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.lang-nav li a:hover {
    color: #fff
}

.active {
    color: #fff;
}
```

But as I am using `e.preventDefault();` it is preventing me to go to `?lang=en` link, How can I achieve this? Any help please.

I have added using onload function:

```
<script>
function checkUrl(){
     var title = document.getElementById("nl").title;
     alert(title);
       if(title == "en"){
         document.getElementById("en").href = '?lang=en';
         document.getElementById("en").style.color = 'red';
         document.getElementById("fr").style.color = 'blue';
         document.getElementById("nl").style.color = 'green';
     }
        if(title == "fr"){
             document.getElementById("en").style.color = '#999999';
             document.getElementById("fr").style.color = 'red';
             document.getElementById("nl").style.color = '#999999';
             document.getElementById("fr").href = '?lang=fr';
         } if(title == "nl"){
             document.getElementById("en").style.color = '#999999';
             document.getElementById("fr").style.color = '#999999';
             document.getElementById("nl").style.color = 'red';
             document.getElementById("nl").href = '?lang=nl';
         }   
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="checkUrl()" >
    <div>
        <div id="header-top">
            <a href="/eidsar" title="Logo"> <img class="logo"
                src="/eidsar/images/MobistarLogo.jpg" />
            </a>
            <ul class="lang-nav">
                <li><a id="en" href="?lang=en" title="en">EN</a></li>
                <li><a id="fr" href="?lang=fr" title="fr">FR</a></li>
                <li><a id="nl" href="?lang=nl" title="nl">NL</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="header-bottom">
            <div style="visibility: hidden" id="header-content">
                <ul class="head-nav"></ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

But now the problem is how to pass the ids in onload???

Comment: if it goes to that link your window will reload and color change will be lost anyways

Comment: Are you trying to color the anchor in header only or you want to color the corresponding anchor tag inside ul tag as well ?

Comment: Also are you loading separate template for each lang on click of the respective link. If so, can you post that as well. Just want to know, how much portion of the page you are using and how is it integrated. Then can be different solutions according to that.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need JQuery to change a `href` color after you clicked it. Try these CSS tags:

```
/* unvisited link */
a:link {
    color: #FF0000;
}

/* visited link */
a:visited {
    color: #00FF00;
}

/* mouse over link */
a:hover {
    color: #FF00FF;
}

/* selected link */
a:active {
    color: #0000FF;
}
```

**Note**: `a:hover` MUST come after `a:link` and `a:visited` in the CSS definition in order to be effective! `a:active` MUST come after `a:hover` in the CSS definition in order to be effective! `Pseudo-class` names are not case-sensitive.

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp

Comment: After navigating to ?lang=en, I need my link color to be same until next language is selected, as this comes in header

Comment: How does this help? It is not going to set the current link's text color when the page is loaded after a navigation.

Comment: I guessed he stayed on one page, then the visited should work for him. If he navigates to different pages he could add classes to the links and have those classes control the styling. Just trying to help and give options, no need to downvote.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are using separate page for each language. In such case you can keep, as per the page the language specific link already colored.  You can use a class like this:
`.header-top a.inuse { color: #999999;}` and assign the class 'inuse' to page specific anchor tags only to highlight only that link on that specific page.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is when the page exits, it wipes everything out. What you would need to do is when the page *loads*, you would have to check to see if the url matches any of the links and set the class/color. So doing anything onclick is useless in your case since you want the page to navigate.

Normally developers will set a class on a link via the serverside code and JavaScript would not worry about it.

Comment: can you tel me how to do that?

Comment: I followed ur approach, but How to pass the differenent ids on page load, I have changed my code. I have added the code pls chk...